# How to prove or understand this linear algebra assertion?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given a matrix $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times k} $, and $B$ has rank $ k $.
Therefore there exists a nonsingular matrix $A=( A_{1},A_{2}) \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} $ such that 
$$
AB= \left[ \begin{array}{lcr} A_1\\A_2\end{array} \right] B=\left[\begin{array}{lcr}I\\0\end{array}\right].
$$

Comment: What did you try? What do you know?  Without knowing something about you, we cannot give an answer suited for you!

Answer (score 1):

This is a sketchy solution.

Using a row permutation (a $0,1$-matrix $P$) we can change the rows of $B$ to $PB$ such that the upper $k \times k$ block of $PB$ is invertible. (Because $B$ must have $k$ linearly independent rows, since it is of rank $k$.) Write
$$
PB = \begin{pmatrix} B_1 \\ B_2 \end{pmatrix},
$$
with $B_1 \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times k}$ invertible and $B_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{(n-k) \times k}$. Now if we choose
$$
A' = \begin{pmatrix} B_1^{-1} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
$$
(where $0$ stands for a block of zeros) we get $A'PB$ of the desired form. Define $A = A'P$, then we have
$$
AB = A'PB = \begin{pmatrix} B_1^{-1} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} B_1 \\ B_2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} B_1^{-1}B_1 + 0 \cdot B_2 \\ 0 \cdot B_1 + 0 \cdot B_2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} I \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}.
$$

Comment: I think everything is correct except for AB=A'PB=A'

Comment: My mistake, I corrected it!

Comment: By the way, is A′P a nonsingular matrix ?

Comment: @BioCoder No it's not.

Comment: If so, A′P doesn't satisfy the requirement @AlgebraicPavel

Answer (score 1):

Since $B$ has full column rank, the matrix $B^TB$ is invertible and the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse $C:=(B^TB)^{-1}B^T\in\mathbb{R}^{k\times n}$ of $B$ satisfies $CB=(B^TB)^{-1}(B^TB)=I$. In addition, the matrix $B^T$ has an $(n-k)$-dimensional nullspace; let $D\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times (n-k)}$ contain its basis in the columns (that is, $D$ has rank $n-k$ and $B^TD=0$). Now set
$$
A:=\begin{bmatrix}
C\\D^T
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
It is easy to verify that this matrix gives $$AB=\begin{bmatrix}I\\0\end{bmatrix}$$
since $CB=I$ and $D^TB=0$.
To show that $A$ is nonsingular, assume that $Ax=0$ for some $x$. It follows that $Cx=0$ (which holds iff $B^Tx=0$) and $D^Tx=0$. Therefore, $x$ is in the nullspace of $B^T$ and at the same time orthogonal to it. This is possible only if $x=0$.